# convert int to short in C

Tags: c, int, short

I have:

```
int a = 2147483647;
short b = (short)a;
```

and I get `b = -1` whereas I expect `int32` to be converted to `int16`(`short`). I expect to see some value and **not** `-1`.

Please someone help me with this.

Comment: I'd say, the value doesn't fit, so the results are undefined.

Comment: `-1` *is* "some value". And the `(short)` cast is unnecessary; the conversion will be done implicitly: `short b = a;`

Comment: @BartFriederichs: The result of the conversion is *implementation-defined*, not undefined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your int A is larger than the size of short.  When you convert A to short, you get a 1 in the left most bit, which is going to indicate that it is a negative number.  Since you're getting -1, I suppose you're getting 1s in all 16 bits, which is going to give you -2^15 + 2^14 + 2^13... + 2^0, which will give you -1. In short (no pun intended), you can't convert the integer to a short if it is too large.

Answer (score 27):

The value 2147483647, or 2<sup>31</sup>-1 overflows a 16-bit integer. Its binary representation is zero in the MSB followed by 31 ones in the remaining bits.

It looks like in your implementation the last 16 bits are taken in the conversion to `short`. When this happens, all of them are set to `1`, resulting in a [2's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of `-1`:

```
32-bit int:   01111111111111111111111111111111
16-bit short: ----------------1111111111111111
```

However, neither the 2-compliment representation nor this behavior in general is part of the C++ standard, so this behavior is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The behavior is not undefined; the result is implementation-defined, meaning that the implementation must document it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: n3690 page 80 4.7(1) says it's implementation defined, not undefined. Not sure if an implementation is free to define it to be undefined behaviour, however :-)

Answer (score 12):

Converting a value to a *signed* type, when the source value doesn't fit in the target type, yields an *implementation-defined* result. That means that any conforming compiler's documentation must document what that result is.

(This is unlike the behavior on overflow of an arithmetic operator. For example:

```
int overflow = INT_MAX + 1;
```

actually has *undefined behavior*. But in either case, you should be careful to write your code so it doesn't trigger this kind of problem.)

For many implementations, for both conversion and arithmetic, an overflow where the target is an N-bit type simply takes the N low-order bits of the correct result.

In your case, apparently `int` is 32 bits and `short` is 16 bits (those sizes can vary on different implementations). `2147483647` is `0x7fffffff`, the low-order 16 bits are `0xffff`, which is (again, on your implementation) the representation of `-1` in type `short`.

For conversion to unsigned types, the result is strictly defined by the standard; it takes the low-order N bits of the result. And for overflowing floating-point conversion (say, converting a very large `double` value to `float`), the behavior is undefined.

So far, this is all the same for C and C++. But just to add to the confusion, starting with the 1999 standard an overflowing signed conversion is permitted to raise an implementation-defined signal. C++ doesn't have this. I don't know of any compiler that actually does this.

> I expect to see some value and **not** `-1`.

`-1` *is* "some value". Was there some specific value you expected?

Incidentally:

```
short b = (short)a;
```

The cast is unnecessary. Assignment, initialization, parameter passing, and `return` statements can assign values between any numeric types without a cast. The value is converted implicitly:

```
short b = a;
```

Answer (score 9):

This is `implementation defined` behavior, for example `gcc` [`Integers Implementation document`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation) says:

> For conversion to a type of width N, the value is **reduced modulo 2^N to be within range** of the type; no signal is raised.

This can differ from compiler to compiler, I am not able to dig up similar documents for `clang` nor `visual studio`.

From the draft C++ standard, section `4.7 Integral conversions` paragraph `3`:

> If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (**and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined**.

If this was `unsigned` then you would have perfectly well defined behavior, as per paragraph `2`:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]

The language is similar in the `C99` draft standard section `6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
uint32_t sum=0xFFFF1234;
uint16_t *p= (uint16_t *) &sum;
uint16_t checksum=p[0];
```

check-sum is `0x1234`.

Here is another way:

```
union ToShort
{
        uint32_t sum;
        uint16_t checksum[2];
} toShort;
toShort.sum=0xFFFF1234;
cout << hex << toShort.checksum[0];
```

output is `1234`.