# How to convert int to short int in C?

Tags: c, integer, bit-shift, short, atoi

Let's say I've got a `char array[5] = {'1','2','3','4','\0'};`.

If I want the integer, I can simply use the atoi()-function:

`int num = atoi(array);`

How could I retrieve the value as short/short int?

Of course, it's given that the value fits in a short.

Do I need to call `atoi()` and work it out with bitshifting?
I'm not quite familiar with that, though.

Comment: `short int num = atoi(array);`.   Of course, this depends on what you want to do when the number is out of range for a short int,  it would improve the question to describe that

Comment: Oh, okay, of course. Doesn't this fail when I have a negative int and I want the short to be negative, too?

Comment: also works with negative.

Comment: No (so long as the value is within range for a short int)

Comment: Might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276225/convert-int-to-short-in-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no ascii to short function, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi only lists `atoi` for ascii to `int`, `atol` for ascii to `long` and `atoll` for ascii to `long long`.

But you can use `atoi` to convert to `int`, then just cast to `short`. Of course this will not check if the number is in the range of a `short`. You might need to check that yourself with something like `SHRT_MIN <= i && i <= SHRT_MAX`.

```
int num = atoi(array);
short s = (short)num;
```

or just directly convert:

```
short s = (short)atoi(array);
```

As others suggested you don't need the explicit cast, but it might help better see what is going on here.

```
short s = atoi(array);  // Implicit cast
```

Comment: A cast is unnecessary as there is implicit conversion

Comment: would be good to have some sort of overflow check, though

Comment: @M.M That was the C++ programmer in me :).

Comment: It's not necessary in C++ either btw

Comment: @M.M That is true and a complete answer should mention that, however an explicit cast shows intent and is less likely to get "fixed" by a subsequent maintainer.  Most static analysis tools for example will flag a warning when assigning to a smaller type, and the maintainer may resolve it by erroneously changing the type rather than applying an explicit casting.

Comment: @Clifford changing the code substantially is likely to be a better solution than using the cast hammer (since this approach is messy to deal with out of range values),  hard to say just from the snippet posted

Comment: @WernerHenze  You should have kept the explicit cast and added the implicit cast example as a third (and probably ill-advised) option.  There are reasons you might use an explicit cast as mentioned above.

Comment: But you need to remember that your short might overflow and it is Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @M.M Agreed.  By using a explicit cast you are saying _"I  did this dangerous thing intentionally"_ - hopefully justified with a comment.  With no cast, no one knows if is intentional or a semantic error.  It may be the input string is constrained or checked elsewhere and is an _input precondition_.  I think it is beyond the scope of the question to deal with range checking; as a comment - fair enough.

Comment: @Clifford it leads to the lint safe code sometimes seen `(void)func((int)34, (char *)mybuff, (const short)x);`

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland It is true that casting everything will circumvent static analysis. And there are some perverse examples. Full type agreement is preferable to type casting, but to know if that were appropriate in this case we'd have to see more code.  At face value, there is no evidence that it is inappropriate in this case.  All the health warnings are valid, but I don't think it warrants addressing in the answer - that's all.

Answer (score 1):

A safer version than simple cast.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

short getshort(const char *num, int *errcode) 
{    
    int result = atoi(num);

    if(errcode)
    {
        *errcode = 0;
        if(result > SHRT_MAX) *errcode = 1;
        else if(result < SHRT_MIN) *errcode = -1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: On reflection, despite my comments elsewhere, this in this case has merit. The overhead of range checking is trivial compared to the atoi conversion. In the general case, you might not want it check all int to short conversions; sometimes a cast can be semantically safe by pre-condition guarantees. There is still an issue of whether whether num is a string that can be converted to an int. If that is assumed, I see no issue with following atoi semantics and simply returning zero if the conversion fails. So an: int atoshrt( const char* ).

Comment: @Clifford returning zero does not inform the caller that the value was invalid. If compiler will inline the code passing NULL will add no overhead https://godbolt.org/z/Pce948

Comment: I know; you missed my point. If atoi() returning  is acceptable, then a shirt version wit the same semantics is acceptable. No error is reported if atoi() fails. Inlining does not remove the overhead of the error check, but again you have missed my point that it is negligible in this case.