# If we have a long variable which we return from a function, and store the returned value in int variable, which bits will be stored?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Suppose there is the following code :

```
unsigned int foo()
{
   unsigned int var = 0x12345678;// assuming 4 bytes
   return var;
}

void bar()
{
    unsigned short res = foo(); //assuming short is 2 bytes
}
```

What can be the expected value of res?

Comment: What did you see?

Comment: https://twiserandom.com/c/what-is-widening-truncation-promotion-and-conversion-between-the-different-c-arithmetic-data-types/index.html#What_is_truncation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert int to short in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276225/convert-int-to-short-in-c)

Comment: `return int;` makes no sense! Did you mean `return var;`?

Comment: The posted code is both wrong and incomplete. Currently we can only guess what the question is really about. Please update the question. Otherwise the question should be deleted.

Comment: @TurePålsson The posted link is for **signed** integers while this (seems) to be about **unsigned** integers. That makes quite a difference.

Comment: @SupportUkraine Ah, you're right. I got so confused by the question changing from (long->int) in the heading to (int->short) in the body, that I didn't notice that the signedness also changed. =)

Comment: The question cannot be answered without knowing the return type of the function, you can't just post pseudo code. (Which of course will not prevent people from posting low quality answers anyway...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last 16 bits should be used as the value of the unsigned short (res).

```
0x12345678 is 10010001101000101011001111000.
```

That would likely make the short be `0101011001111000 = 0x5678`

Comment: The question cannot be answered since it's some sort of pseudo code. But other than that, conversions to unsigned type are well-defined and do _not_ depend on compiler.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code (no `unsigned int foo()`, and `return int` instead of `return var`). I'm sure someone will edit.

C99 says:

6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
[..] if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
until the value is in the range of the new type.

So, assuming `unsigned short` on your platform has a range of 0..65535, the value of res would be 0x12345678 - 65536*n, or 0x12345678 % 65536 = 0x5678.

Comment: Too much guessing here.... If the missing definition of `foo` is supposed to be `int foo()` this answer is incomplete.... but notice that `var` inside `foo` is actually `unsigned int` so maybe it's really `unsigned int foo()` and that is another story....

Comment: @SupportUkraine Whether foo returns unsigned int or int is irrelevant, since 0x12345678 fits in an int.

Comment: @MagnusWibeck In order to keep a good answer that covers the general case, it matters

Answer (score 0):

Size of int is 32 bit and size of short is 16 bit. Then the value of variable res will be 0x5678.

Comment: And why is that?